# Android: Using a method to initialize associate spinners with views causing null pointer exception

Tags: android, view, methods, null, spinner

I'm writing an app with quite a lot of spinners in it. In order to make things more concise, I made a method that associates a spinner with a view and array adapter. However, I'm getting a null pointer exception whenever I try to use that spinners (e.g set Visibility).

Here's my code:

```
private void setSpinners() {
    ManureID = R.id.smanure;
    ApplicationID = R.id.sapplication;
    SlurryID = R.id.sslurry;
    MaturityID = R.id.smaturity;
    TimingID = R.id.stiming;
    SoilTypeID = R.id.ssoil;
    PreviousCropID = R.id.scropping;
    GrassRotationID = R.id.sgrassrot;
    RainID = R.id.srain;
    StrawID = R.id.sstraw;
    PID = R.id.sp;
    KID = R.id.sk;
    MgID = R.id.smg;

    // TODO update slurry values depending
    setSpinner(SlurryID, Slurry, slurrys);
    setSpinner(ApplicationID, Application, application);
    setSpinner(ManureID, Manure, manures);
    setSpinner(MaturityID, Maturity, maturity);
    setSpinner(TimingID, Timing, timing);
    setSpinner(SoilTypeID, SoilType, soilTypes);
    setSpinner(PreviousCropID, PreviousCrop, previousCrops);
    setSpinner(GrassRotationID, GrassRotation, grassRotations);
    setSpinner(RainID, Rain, rain);
    setSpinner(StrawID, Straw, straw);
    setSpinner(PID, P, p);
    setSpinner(KID, K, k);
    setSpinner(MgID, Mg, mg);
}

private void setSpinner(int ID, Spinner spinner, ArrayList<String> list) {
    spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(ID);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapt = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            ID, list);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapt);
}
```

I'm assuming that the method is at fault. Is it not actually associating views with spinners correctly? Is there a way to fix the method?

Thanks!

Comment: Post stack trace... It is impotant where youre calling this method...

Comment: I don't know how much you'd gain from that. Any method called from any of the Spinners (e.g. Slurry.something()) after the function setSpinners is called throws a null pointer exception.

I can repost the whole code and stack trace if you think it will help, but I'm 99% sure the problem is due to the way I've used a method to set the Spinners.

Answer (score 1):

You always find just one spinner in ***setSpinner*** method right here 

 ***spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(ID);*** 
. at last you will be able to use the spinner with ***R.id.smg*** id.

you need to do is this:

```
public void SetAllSpinners(int rootID) {
 ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) findViewById(rootID);
  for (int i = 0; i < vg.getChildCount(); i++) {
   View v = vg.getChildAt(i);
     /*
     Here check all the layouts that you used to contain your spinners
     */
     if(v instanceof LinearLayout || v instanceof RelativeLayout){
        SetAllSpinners(v.getId());
     }
     if (v instanceof Spinner) {
     Spinner sx = (Spinner) v;
     ArrayAdapter<String> adapt = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, ID,
                    list);
     sx.setAdapter(adapt);
        }
    }
}
```

you have to call this method like:

```
SetAllSpinners(R.id.rootLayoutThatContainsYourSpinners);
```

after setting the array adapter you can set your events there.
let me know if this works please..

Comment: Won't this method assign the same list to every spinner?

Comment: Yes you are right. In here:                           if (v instanceof Spinner) {
     Spinner sx = (Spinner) v;
     ArrayAdapter<String> adapt = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, ID,
                    list);
     sx.setAdapter(adapt);
        }
    }    //before creating new array adapter  use a method that you wrote.which takes spinnerid and returns appropriate list. And send that list to arrayadapter constructor. I'm writing from mobile so answer will look messy, sorry